# Binding multiple array into single list view in android

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, binding

I am new to android and I was working in the android list view&array.I had certain string arrays

```
try{
    String subString=colValue.text();
    String[] strArray1=subString.split("//certain regex");
    String[] strArray2=subString.split("//certain regex");
    String[] strArray3=subString.split("//certain regex");
    return strArray1;
}
```

I have the list view like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {            
        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listShow);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

my listview.xml

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listShow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnData" />
```

I have added the list view.But I cannot access the `string array variable`

```
try{
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strArray1));
       list.addAll(Arrays.asList(strArray2));
       String [] outResult= (String[]) listString.toArray();
       return outResult;


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How to bind the array values into single list view .help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try{
            List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(resultArray));
            listString.addAll(Arrays.asList(resultArray1));
            String [] outResult= new String[listString.size()];
            int i=0;
            for(String str: listString){
                outResult[i]=str;
                i++;
            }
            return outResult;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have the arrays `strArray1`, `strArray2` and `strArray3`, but can only figure out how to pass one of them to the `arrayAdapter`. Is this correct?

If that is the case, maybe you could append the arrays to each other, so that you only have one array - Which you can then pass to the adapter?

Alternatively, you could return the arrays as a `List`, and make an `Adapter` that takes a list of strings?

EDIT: I imagined something like this:

```
try{
    String subString = colValue.text();
    List<String> entries = new List<String>();
    entries.addAll(subString.split("//certain regex"));
    entries.addAll(subString.split("//certain regex"));
    entries.addAll(subString.split("//certain regex"));
    return entries;
}
```

,

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {            
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listShow);
        ListAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ListAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: so which one is best append all the array together and passing to the adapter or make an adapter for every list ?

Comment: I don't think it would make sense to create multiple adapters. My first option would be to just append the arrays on each other so you have one big array containing `strArray1` `strArray2` and `strArray3`

Comment: Edited answer as well. I'm still not a hundred that we're on the same page, but take a look.

Comment: I have just append all arrays into arraylist and then convert to string array bcoz am using the return variable as     string[]

Comment: That's fair. But what is the problem now then? You return all your values as an array of strings, and you pass that array to the adapter. Problem solved?

Comment: my app crashed .what i do

Comment: Can't possibly know that without seeing the crash log.